# playwright capture TEXT AREA by using Python

Tags: python, request, playwright

Lets consider as Text area contains some text; it would be captured before and after

Whereas, unable to capture TExT area due to JS script. Is it any solution on that ? Sample code below and let me know what is missing

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def run(playwright):
    chrome = playwright.chromium
    browser = chrome.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(url_text)
    page.fill('textarea#startText',"this is Text area")
    page.locator('span#btnSpellLabel').click()
    page.wait_for_load_state('load')
   
    response =  session.get(page.url)
    print(response.html.find('div#inside'))
    print(response.html.find('div[class="results text_box"]'))
    print(response.html.find('form[@id="area"] div'))
    page.wait_for_timeout(5000)

    browser.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_text = 'https://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/'
    session  = HTMLSession()

     
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can improve there.

- First, you can read the text area value using `page.locator('#startText').value()`
- Then, you click on the check button. Don't wait using `wait_for_load_state`, because the page is not navigating.
- After the check action there is an `SPAN` element inside the "#inside" div. You can do `page.locator('#inside SPAN').inner_html()`. The `inner_html` function will wait for the element for you.

Comment: A bit confused with an existing code. Hence, cleared, then used your in outs as stated. I'm new pie on Playwright for data analytics works. Normally using simple code standards for data verification; playwright in on track now.. Once again thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: # values entered in TextArea
    page.fill('textarea#startText',"this is actons")
    value = page.query_selector('textarea#startText')
        #confirm TextArea as expected input
    print(value.input_value())

    # Check Grammar
    page.locator('span#btnSpellLabel').click()

    # Verify Final Corrected value
    valux = page.locator('div#inside.results.text_box')
    print('\n',valux.inner_text())